# Removing Digits From XML Element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to remove digits from an elements that are located from child elements.  Can anyone help with with the xslt needed for this?  Here is an example that should remove "_0" from the element "mgt_interface_0" .  Thanks in advance!

Piece from source XML:

```
<mgt_interfaces dataType="fXml">
         <number_of_mgt_interfaces dataType="fInt">1</number_of_mgt_interfaces>
         <mgt_interface_0 dataType="fXml" modelIndex="0">
            <ip_address dataType="fSting">###.##.###.###</ip_address>
            <name dataType="fString">Port</name>
            <netmask dataType="fString">###.###.###.###</netmask>
            <gateway dataType="fString">###.##.###.###</gateway>
            <mac_address dataType="fString">##:##:##:##:##:##</mac_address>
            <state dataType="fString">Enabled</state>
         </mgt_interface_0>

Output XML:

<mgt_interfaces dataType="fXml">
         <number_of_mgt_interfaces dataType="fInt">1</number_of_mgt_interfaces>
         <mgt_interface dataType="fXml" modelIndex="0">
            <ip_address dataType="fSting">###.##.###.###</ip_address>
            <name dataType="fString">Port</name>
            <netmask dataType="fString">###.###.###.###</netmask>
            <gateway dataType="fString">###.##.###.###</gateway>
            <mac_address dataType="fString">##:##:##:##:##:##</mac_address>
            <state dataType="fString">Enabled</state>
         </mgt_interface_0>
```

I do not have much experience in XSLT so I need some help and suggestions.  Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72913583/16462950

Comment: Well, start by deciding which XSLT processor and version of XSLT you are using or want to use and then look at the relevant XPath function library for the version, all available on the web as W3C recommendations. XPath 1.0 has `translate` as your swiss army knife of string manipulations, XPath 2.0 and later also have regular expression support with the `replace` function. New elements are constructed with `xsl:element`.

Comment: Going from `mgt_interface_0` to `mgt_interface` requires more than just removing  digits. It's not clear if you know the names of the numbered elements in advance or not. We need a better definition of the rules you want to apply.  And as mentioned, knowing which XSLT version you can use is important.  Even more importantly: a request for someone to write your code for you is not a legitimate question. Post you best attempt at this.

Comment: I was not looking for anyone to write the code for me.  Only suggestions.  But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance that the numbered elements are named `mgt_interface_0`, `mgt_interface_1`, `mgt_interface_2` etc. then you can remove the numbering quite simply using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'mgt_interface_')]">
    <mgt_interface>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </mgt_interface>
</xsl:template>
          
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, this assumes there are no elements named `mgt_interface_detail`, for example.

Comment: That is useful.  Again, I was not looking for the solution but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove *all digits* and also remaining trailing underscores, the XSLT-1.0 code would be a bit more complicated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output  method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity Transform -->
    <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
         <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
         </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="wo_numbers" select="translate(name(),'0123456789','')" />
        <xsl:variable name="new_name">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($wo_numbers) != string-length(name())">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring($wo_numbers,string-length($wo_numbers),1)='_'">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($wo_numbers,1,string-length($wo_numbers)-1)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$wo_numbers" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="{$new_name}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For your example given, the output should be as expected.

Comment: This changes the name of element  `item1_abc` to `item_abc` - which I believe is wrong.

Comment: Yes, this is what it does. The code above removes _all digits_. I mentioned that in the introduction. If that was not wanted, this answer wouldn't be a good fit for the author, but maybe for someone else finding this question with this particular title.

Comment: If your intent is to remove all digits then I believe this could be a lot simpler. But I still think the goal here is to fix numbered elements only.